# using omniauth with mobile flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

in the working project on rails 4 is used omniauth gem for social authorization, connected some social networks
and the appropriate gems are used

- omniauth-facebook
- omniauth-instagram
- omniauth-google-oauth2

now there was a task to add api for mobile authorization, where the scheme is somewhat different:

- client starts oauth flow w/ Facebook (using login button etc)
- client gets access token and posts back to server
- server looks up user via (FB/Instagram/Google) api call w/ token
- server does lookup/create of user based on uid & provider
- user is logged in if a user association lookup is successful

Help me please how to use received access token from mobile in omniauth and not duplicate the functionality

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem through monkey patching build_access_token method, in this method i check the presence params[:access_token] parameter